# java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: specialChr and lower case cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

```
java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 specialChr cannot be resolved to a variable
 lowerCase cannot be resolved to a variable
```

getting error exception earlier working fine with the same code.

I have local variable also but all the time getting error in lower case and spec case

```
@Test(priority = 5)
public void npaCheckUpSignUpReschedulingAndCancellingAppointment()
        throws IOException, BiffException, InterruptedException {
    // generating user-name, password and confirm password.
    String userName = generateRandom(aToZ);
    System.out.println("UserName: " + userName);
    log = Logger.getLogger(CheckUpNPA.class);
    log.info("npaCheckUpSignUpReschedulingAndCancellingAppointment - Username: " + userName + "");
    // item 1
    WebElement createUserName = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id=" + readExcel(74, 3, 0) + "]"));
    fluientWaitforElement(createUserName, 20, 5);
    isElementPresent(createUserName);
    createUserName.sendKeys(userName);
// generating special character for password
    String specialCharacter = generateRandomSpecial(specialChr);
    // generating upper case character for the password
    String upperCaseCharacter = generateupperCase(upperCase);
    // generating lower case character for the password
    String lowerCaseCharacter = generatelowerCase(lowerCase);
    // generating number for the password
    String number = generatenumeral(numerals);
    String passWord = upperCaseCharacter + lowerCaseCharacter + specialCharacter + number;
    System.out.println("PassWord: " + passWord);
    log = Logger.getLogger(CheckUpNPA.class);
    log.info("npaCheckUpSignUpReschedulingAndCancellingAppointment - Password: " + passWord + "");
```

Code should be work with the same string spec char and lower case.

Comment: where is the variable  specialChr declared?

Comment: @NehaArora Can you show us how `generateRandomSpecial(specialChr)` is defined?

Comment: This might be happening because methods 'generateRandomSpecial','generateupperCase','generatelowerCase' may not be returning a String type variable.

Comment: // to generate only lower case alphabet for password
 public static String generatelowerCase(String lowerCase) {
  Random rand = new Random();
  StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
   int randIndex = rand.nextInt(lowerCase.length());
   res.append(lowerCase.charAt(randIndex));
  }
  return res.toString();
 }